# how to create validator for lowercase user in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django

my site is up and running. However, silly me I didnt put in a validator to check if users and username can only be in lower-case (I only realised that DJANGO allowed capitalized Users and usernames). Although, I have put up a warning but users usually ignore that still write upper case letters or alteast capitalized letters in their signup forms. I then encounter the problem of slugs not working, thereafter I have to manually change their usernames. I do not want to change the behavior of slugs and instead can I please ask for help from someone in changing my views? I have tried .lower() .format() as well and it didnt work. I am very weak on validators.

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):

    captcha = CaptchaField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length= 15, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
           model = User
           fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

Views.py

```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
   from django.views import generic
   from django.views.generic import View
   from home.forms import SignUpForm



  class SignUpFormView(View):
form_class = SignUpForm
template_name = 'home/signup.html'

#if there is no sign up yet
def get(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


#if going to sig up
def post(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)


    if form.is_valid():
        #it takes information but does save it
        user = form.save(commit = False)
        #cleaned normalized data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()




        #returns if it is all correct

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("userprofile:newprofile")

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: django doesn't cares about case in username, user can login by entering username in lower or upper. eg `Username`, `username`, `USERNAME`, `UsErNaMe` are all same and will log in the user without any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a validation in the `SignupForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):

    captcha = CaptchaField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length= 15, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if not data.islower():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Usernames should be in lowercase")
        return data

    class Meta:
           model = User
           fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

So in case the `data.islower()` check fails (the `username` contains uppercase characters), it will raise a `ValidationError`, and thus the form is not valid.

Note that `islower()` only checks *case-based characters*, so if the string contains digits, it will still succeed. You thus might want to finetune the check. Or as specified in the [documentation of **`str.islower`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower):

> Return `True` if all cased characters in the string are lowercase and
>   there is at least one cased character, `False` otherwise.

An alternative might be to convert the data to lowercase, such that a user that enters `'FooBar'` gets as username `foobar`, although this can result in the fact that users get confused that the username they picked is *not* the username they get.

Comment: perfect Willem you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `username = form.cleaned_data['username']` to `username = form.cleaned_data['username'].lower()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validator.

1. create validators.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_lower_case(value):
    if not value.islower():
        raise ValidationError('You must use only lowercase letters!')
```

2. your models

```
from django.db import models
from .validators import validate_lower_case


class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_lower_case])
```